Problemas a la hora de copiar/pegar en oracle sql developer desde un notepad++
Si quiero copiar/pegar dentro del programa Oracle SQL developer no hay ningún problema, pero si intento copiar algo externo, bien sea de una página web o de cualquier otra cosa no me lo permite. No marca ningún error pero no lo realiza.
Si alguien pudiera echar una mano se lo agradecería.
Un saludo a todos.

Tienes habilitada la visualización en la bios de tu pc?

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
